# What's the meaning of "undercurrents" here?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

I'm translating a text into Spanish and I don't fully understand this sentence (undercurrents):

A guy has just returned from a travel. But in fact he's plotting against the government and his journey had to do with that, although the doctor doesn't know anything about it (the others do, though).

> "We've thought we'd come over for dinner, to catch up. I'm sure that he's brought all kinds of exciting news from there", the doctor went on to say, cheerfully oblivious to the **undercurrents**.

Undercurrents = oblivious to what his words were really implying?

Undercurrents = oblivious to what was really happening?

Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undercurrents aside...

"We've thought we'd..." - Very uncomfortable form.
"We thought we'd.." - Far better

Actual answer...
Undercurrents = oblivious to what was really happening
The others knew what was going on, yet he didn't.